# How I can translate the strings of third-party python modules using gettext

Tags: python, gettext

On assignment, I need a localized CLI application, for these purposes I decided to use `gettext`, but ran into the problem of localizing the standard output of the `click` module. Are there any ways to localize strings of third-party modules?

Below I presented a typical code for the `click` module along with `gettext`.

```py
import click
import gettext

ru = gettext.translation('app', localedir='locale', languages=['ru'])
ru.install()

@click.command()
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When creating a .pot file, it is possible to localize only my code, but I'm interested in the localization of third-party modules too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever will need to do this, relatively clean and easy way of translating third-party libraries locally is to use [Babel extractor](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/cmdline.html) while passing additional paths to it - like that (I did it with [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dwolfhub/zxcvbn-python) where needed strings are already marked as translatable:

```
ZXCVBN_DIR=`python -c "import zxcvbn; import pathlib; print(pathlib.Path(zxcvbn.__file__).parent, end='')"`
pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -o locale/messages.pot my_module_dir ${ZXCVBN_DIR}
```

Env variable assignment syntax  may vary in case of using `make` or running commands in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

There are no easy ways, so I will have to search and change the string in the click module myself.